# Where should I ask this question about mass panic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following question but I don't know which site within the Stack Exchange network I can post this question:

> ### What to do during mass panic?
>
> There are lots of situations of course.
>
> I began to think about the topic while reading [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bucharest%20fire&rlz=1CDGOYI_enSK591SK591&hl=en-US&prmd=imnv&source=univ&tbm=nws&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0CB8QsQRqFQoTCLmLn7bt7MgCFYN4DgodraUH4w) news report about fire in closed space during concert (pyrotechnic failure).
>
> How should one, perhaps group of two (close one) /three people behave during fire? One exit available (I guess) and lots of people running for their life.
>
> Should I / we wait aside, so most people get away and avoid getting stomped at?
>
> I know there is a lot of variables, perhaps mention couple of them in your answer.

Comment: Probably nowhere on the SE network. Even if a related topic has a SE site, the question is super vague

Comment: @Pëkka oh, I agree, I am really interested in topic therefore I would like to ask. - asking won't hurt anyone. (I might write an email to fire dept.). What is **not** vague though?

Comment: [Emergency Preparedness and Prepping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89744/emergency-preparedness-prepping)

Comment: Kyslik, I appreciate your enthusiasm, but I'm afraid asking *does* hurt -- it clutters up a site's front page with a question that is not a good fit for the site, thus making the site harder to use and making it harder for others to find good questions and good answers.  The fact that you are really interested in the topic does not mean it is a good idea to ask a question that doesn't fit the site's scope or that is unclear/vague/shows no evidence of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [current list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#) I don't think your question would fit any site.

The closest match I could think of would be [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) but their [Help Centre](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is for researchers, academics, students, and anyone else needing expert answers to advanced questions in the cognitive sciences.

> If you have questions about ...

> - Cognitive science

- Psychology (e.g., cognitive, social, developmental, biological, applied, clinical, organizational, etc.)
- Psychiatry
- Neuroscience and neurobiology

> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question.

and your question has some attributes that, when loosely interpreted, relate to these topic. Based on my interpretation I find some related questions [1](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/what-characterises-people-who-stay-calm-in-crisis-situations), [2](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/search?q=group), [3](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/search?q=fight+flight) but they are all more asked with a science background while your question seems to address more a practical issue.

You could give it a try at their [meta](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/) but don't have high hopes. There are other sites, like [Quora](http://quora.com) and [Reddit](http://reddit.com) that are better equipped for questions that don't have a finite answer.

On Area 51 you'll find [Emergency Preparedness and Prepping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89744/emergency-preparedness-prepping)  (tnx [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268736/where-should-i-ask-this-question-about-mass-panic/268741#comment871075_268736)), you could support that proposal but the site isn't in beta yet.

Comment: What about Travel.SE? CogSci has low expert headcount, Travel at least has some rather experienced folks.

Comment: That could be a competing answer @DeerHunter

Comment: I don't have an account on Travel, hence it would be impolite of me to recommend going to a site I don't frequent and do not understand the nuances of on-topicness of. (Hmmm, another dangling preposition :| )

Comment: I don't have an account anywhere, didn't see that as impolite to suggest a site as long as I keep referring to the help center and advice to seek help on meta, no matter how good it fits.

Comment: @DeerHunter honestly, I'm not sure about Travel.SE. This question can apply in daily life, not only when traveling. Even it can happen at work office. :/

Comment: @AndrewT. - absolutely agree, but one has to look for a site where the relevant expertise may be, and not just armchair theorists (although it is really really hard to survive a stampede).

Comment: Let's hope the armchair theorists over on CogSci are not easily offended...  ;)